# The --memory-init-file is no longer supported

Tags: python, emscripten

I started using emscripten with Python to deploy my game to the web and it looks
like the flag `--memory-init-file` is no longer valid and breaks the build.

The github repo isn't sharing any older releases of the code so I cannot use older version of the code and carry on.

```
mark@eli:~/deploy_test/panda3d$ python3.8 makepanda/makepanda.py --nothing --use-python --use-vorbis --use-bullet --use-zlib --use-freetype --use-harfbuzz --use-openal --no-png --use-direct --use-gles2 --optimize 4 --static --target emscripten --threads 4
Version: 1.11.0
Platform: emscripten-wasm32
Using Python 3.8
Target OS: emscripten
Target arch: wasm32
shared:INFO: (Emscripten: Running sanity checks)
Generating dependencies...
WARNING: file depends on Python but is not in an ABI-specific directory: built/bin/deploy-stub.js
[T1] Building C++ object built/tmp/interrogate_composite1.o
[T2] Linking executable built/bin/interrogate_module.js
[T3] Building C++ object built/tmp/parse_file_parse_file.o
[T4] Building C++ object built/tmp/test_interrogate_test_interrogate.o
em++: error: --memory-init-file is no longer supported
The following command returned a non-zero value: em++ -o built/bin/interrogate_module.js -Lbuilt/lib -Lbuilt/tmp built/tmp/interrogate_module_interrogate_module.o built/tmp/interrogate_module_preamble_python_native.o built/tmp/libp3cppParser.a built/lib/libp3dtool.a built/lib/libp3dtoolconfig.a built/lib/libp3interrogatedb.a -s WARN_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=1 --memory-init-file 0 -s EXIT_RUNTIME=1 -O3
Storing dependency cache.
Elapsed Time: 2 sec
Build process aborting.
Build terminated.
```

Can you please advise on how can I go about troubleshooting this ?

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode